# Why a Macbook Pro Retina can't open a big folder of images without freezing?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, macbook, freeze

I have a folder with 60000 32x32 images. Opening that folter on my Macbook Pro Retina causes it to freeze for almost a minute. Also, navigating from one image to another displays a lag on the Finder preview. How is it possible that we stream HD videos realtime to the other side of the world, yet such powerful computer, with SSD storage, takes a full minute to list ~40 images from the HD?

Comment: A short answer is: reading a file is more than just reading single pixels. I'm afraid a complete explaination would be too long to fit here, but you can get some good clues.

Answer (score 2):

The long delay is caused by the Mac having to go through such a large number of individual files. Even a fast computer with an SSD has limits. If you want to view some of the images much more quickly, place smaller numbers of files into sub-folders created in the original folder. If you want to access just a few by name, then once you have them in sub folders use Spotlight to find and open the ones you want by name.